# What is the empty box for on this comic cover?

Tags: comics, art, publishing

Here is an example from the Lucifer series:

[image: Here is an example from the Lucifer series.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the publisher’s information, appearing in its initial monthly print, but typically omitted from collected reprints.

You can see an example of the populated version from *Lucifer* #17, which was the first part of your storyline, Dalliance of the Damned, pt. 1, located here:
https://comicvine.gamespot.com/a-dalliance-with-the-damned/4045-55706/

A technical correction, this information typically occurs within the issue (not on cover), typically on the first page, which in monthly comic books also usually happens to be a “splash page,” or full-page art. Some comics, modern Marvel books for example, sacrifice this first page to include some type of “story so far” introductions to characters and current storyline. They do this so that portion of splash-page type art isn’t ruined by this information.